# Dictionary KeyError in PyQt

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt, pyqt4, keyerror

I'm not too sure how to explain my problem, but I want certain trigger letters to output a certain phrase, just as done [here](http://pastebin.com/LwjbbmCt). But in [my code](http://pastebin.com/1KnKBvB4) in PyQt (yes I'm doing it the poor way by using the designer, but it is what it is), the 30th line:

```
self.print_order.setText(ORDER[i])
```

is getting this error:

> KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'a')

and I'm not too sure how to proceed. If the question doesn't make sense, then I'll try explain it further if need be.

Comment: I think `QString`s don't hash to the same value as Python strings.  I've little doubt this is answered elsewhere on SO already but I can't find it... Probably you should convert the `QString` to a `unicode` object.  By the way, you probably want to use `.get(i)` not `[i]`, because it is possible to type many characters (what about a space?  punctuation?  emoji?  French accented character?  Chinese character?  etc!).

Comment: By the way, if I remember correctly this only comes up in Python 2, not Python 3

Comment: `self.print_order.setText(ORDER.get(unicode(i), ''))`.

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I was after! Really appreciate the help.